# Code migration from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2019 failed in Visual studio 2019

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2019

I have custom C# code which was written for SharePoint 2013 using Visual Studio 2015. When I opened that solution in Visual Studio 2019 Ent for SharePoint 2019, it asked me to upgrade/migrate.

After upgrade also I got some missing SharePoint DLL reference errors. I fixed them by referring from ISAPI folder. However all build errors are gone but when I deploy solution on a SharePoint 2019 site I get 0 error but build fails and says 1 failed.

[image: Build error with 0 error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rare, but it happens, use PowerShell to redeploy the assembly:

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity "sptimerjob.wsp" -GACDeployment  -force -CompatibilityLevel {15}  -WebApplication http://sp-2013:7000
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, it was the the SharePoint code generator tool was not running when we upgrade the code.

Designer.cs files must be regenerated for new environment which was not happening to 100% of the webparts. We did it manually and it worked. (Right click on .ascx 'Run custom tool' is the option, for uninitiated)